# Find volume of a rotation

Tags: calculus, integration

An arc of a curve $y=\frac{|x|}{1+x^2}$ is rotating around $O_{x^{-}}$ axis. Find the volume of a shape after rotation.

Local maximum of a function $y$ are $M_1(1,\frac{1}{2}),M_2(-1,\frac{1}{2})$.

I don't understand how to find the volume of a shape. I know the limits of integration (integrating along $x$ axis for $0$ to $1$, and times two because of the symmetry) but can't understand what function needs to be integrated.

The volume is $V=\int_0^1 2\pi(\frac{x}{1+x^2})^2\mathrm dx$

Question: Why is the integrated function $\pi(\frac{x}{1+x^2})^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plot of the curve and surface generated by revolving the curve about $O_x$:

[image]

The volume is computed by essentially taking the sum of an infinite number of circular areas (the cross-sections of the solid generated by revolving about $O_x$). Each area depends on the radius of each circle, which is given by the vertical distance from the curve to $O_x$ - this radius is then $\dfrac{|x|}{1+x^2}$.

Recalling that the area of a circle with radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$, you then have
$$\text{Volume}=\sum_{\text{all circles}}\pi r^2=\int_a^b \pi\left(\frac{|x|}{1+x^2}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$$